# Error while executing the cfc : The value returned from the function is not of type json

Tags: coldfusion, cfc

I have written a web-service in ColdFusion which returns message (success/failure) by checking the input values in the database. 
To run the cfc, I am directly providing the arguments in the URL, like this:
**http://localhost/AimsWeb/Authenticate2.cfc?method=AuthenticateUser&returnformat=json&CustomerID=1&username=xxx&password=xxxx**
But when I run this page, it ends with an error like below:
[image]

This is my CFC:

```
<cfcomponent rest="true" restpath="/AimsWeb"> <!--- REST Service--->

<cffunction name="AuthenticateUser" access="remote" httpmethod="POST"  returnFormat="JSON" returntype="json">

<!---- Defining Arguments--->
    <cfargument name="Username" type="string" required="Yes">
    <cfargument name="Password" type="string" required="Yes">
    <cfargument name="CustomerID" type="string" required="Yes">

<!---- Setting the Form Values (which we will get from AW+) and setting it to arguments passed--->
    <cfset Form.CustomerID = arguments.CustomerID>
    <cfset Form.Username = arguments.Username>
    <cfset Form.Password = Hash(arguments.Password)>

<cfif StructKeyExists (form, 'CustomerID') and StructKeyExists(form, 'UserName') and StructKeyExists (form, 'password')>
   <cfquery name="AllUsers" datasource="#Application.GomDatasource#">
    SELECT u.UserTypeID, u.UserID, u.CustomerID, u.UserName, u.Password
     FROM tblUsers u
    WHERE u.CustomerID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#Form.CustomerID#">
   </cfquery>



<!--- This is to check whether provided parameters are valid by checking the same in the database--->
<cfset local.StatusStruct = StructNew()>

<cfif form.customerid EQ "" OR form.username EQ "" OR form.password EQ "">
    <cfset local.StatusStruct['errorCode'] = 400>
    <cfset local.StatusStruct['errorMessage'] = "Insufficient Input.">

<cfelseif AllUsers.RecordCount AND form.CustomerId EQ AllUsers.CustomerID AND form.username EQ AllUsers.UserName AND form.password EQ AllUsers.Password>
    <cfset local.StatusStruct['errorCode'] = 200>
    <cfset local.StatusStruct['errorMessage'] = "Success">

<cfelseif AllUsers.CustomerID NEQ form.CustomerID>
    <cfset local.StatusStruct['errorCode'] = 400>
    <cfset local.StatusStruct['errorMessage'] = "Customer Id doesn't exist">

 <cfelseif AllUsers.UserName NEQ form.UserName>
    <cfset local.StatusStruct['errorCode'] = 400>
    <cfset local.StatusStruct['errorMessage'] = "User not found">

 <cfelseif AllUsers.Password NEQ form.password>
    <cfset local.StatusStruct['errorCode'] = 400>
    <cfset local.StatusStruct['errorMessage'] = "Invalid Password">
</cfif>

    <!--- Returning the status in JSON form--->

</cfif>
<cfreturn local.StatusStruct>
  </cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Where is the part where you convert local.StatusStruct to json?

Comment: User and password in the url...why?

Comment: @DanBracuk:  I believe if we specify returnFormat=“json” and this would automatically convert the return value into a JSON string.. (?)

Comment: @Hackerman: I am just passing the username, password as an argument to run the cfc ( as i don't wanna write the invoke page )

Comment: Also you are pasting that url in your browser, then it's a get request...you need to perform a post request, because you have this `httpmethod="POST"`

Comment: Oh, i have removed that url part, but no success - :( http://localhost/AimsWeb/Authenticate2.cfc?task=yes&method=AuthenticateUser&CustomerID=1&username=xxx&password=xxxx

Comment: Have you checked you application log on the server for an error?  Or use a `cftry` in the function?

Comment: Also, I didn't think `json` was a valid type in CF, i.e. the `returntype='json'`.  According to the code, the `returntype` should be struct.

Comment: Guys, it worked. The returntype=json was not valid. I removed that line and it worked. Thanks ALL for your help. Thanks @snackboy

Answer (score 2):

it worked. The `returntype=json` was not valid. I removed that line and it worked.

```
<cffunction name="AuthenticateUser" access="remote" httpmethod="GET"  returnFormat="JSON">
```

Thanks ALL for your help.